# composer always installs latest version of the package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have made two new releases `v1.0.0` and `v0.2.0` of my package [mailbase](https://github.com/tkeer/mailbase).

The `v1.0.0` has package constraint ^7.0

```
"laravel/framework": "^7.0"
```

The `v0.2.0` has package constraint

```
"laravel/framework": "^5.0|^6.0"
```

But when I install this package

```
composer require tkeer/mailbase
```

the composer always install `v1.0.0` irrespective of laravel version (laravel5, laravel6 or laravel7). Shouldn't it install `v0.2.0` for laravel6 and laravel5?

Comment: What's the problem? If you want to install a specific version, you can specify that further when calling `composer require`

Comment: How can I make composer to pick best fit version instead of explicitly specifying a version?

Answer (score 2):

Actually Your composer.json of plugin is telling this

V1.0.0 can only run on Laravel 7.0 and greater

v0.2.0 can run on all Laravel from 5.0 to  6.0
v0.2.0 can run on all Laravel from 6.0 to  7.0

Adding ^6.0 make is available from version 6.0 to 7.0

If I unable to explain this,please see this URL for more information

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints

```
"require": {
    "vendor/package": "1.3.2", // exactly 1.3.2

    // >, <, >=, <= | specify upper / lower bounds
    "vendor/package": ">=1.3.2", // anything above or equal to 1.3.2
    "vendor/package": "<1.3.2", // anything below 1.3.2

    // * | wildcard
    "vendor/package": "1.3.*", // >=1.3.0 <1.4.0

    // ~ | allows last digit specified to go up
    "vendor/package": "~1.3.2", // >=1.3.2 <1.4.0
    "vendor/package": "~1.3", // >=1.3.0 <2.0.0

    // ^ | doesn't allow breaking changes (major version fixed - following semver)
    "vendor/package": "^1.3.2", // >=1.3.2 <2.0.0
    "vendor/package": "^0.3.2", // >=0.3.2 <0.4.0 // except if major version is 0
}
```

Comment: ^6.0 is actually equals to >=6.0.0 <7.0.0! isn't it? Example given by the website stats that ^0.3 is treated as >=0.3.0 <0.4.0 (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-)

Comment: You are correct I wanted to type up til 7.0 i.e excluding 7.0 and greater

Answer (score 1):

composer always select latest version to install

here's syntax to install packages via composer

```
composer require vendor/package:version
```

specify version to install

```
composer require tkeer/mailbase:0.2.0
```

Comment: composer doesn't always install latest version, it installs latest version falling in given constraints.

Answer (score 0):

On running `composer require tkeer/mailbase` without any further version constraint, Composer computes which versions of that package are compatible with the other currently required packages. The **latest** possible version is installed.

In your example: if you already have Laravel v5 or v6 installed, the latest possible version of that package to be installed is v0.2.0, as v1.0.0 is compatible with Laravel v7 only. Likewise, if Laravel v7 is installed, v1.0.0 of your package is installed, as the prior version v0.2.0 is not compatible with Laravel v7.

If you use `composer require tkeer/mailbase:"v1.0.0"` while Laravel v5 or v6 is installed, an error message will be thrown, as this package is not compatible.

Comment: This is what I think, but problem is that composer installs `v1.0.0` for laravel5 and laravel6 too.

Comment: @MTauqeer can you share your initial `composer.json` by editing the question? I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: I could reproduce it on freshly installed laravel6.

Comment: So .. ? I'm stuck with the same issue and no answer here.. What did you do to solve ?